# appending tags in d3 without nesting

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to generate html that has a tooltip and tooltip text for each `<p>` tag. I know that I can do all the tooltip stuff in d3, but I'm using a css style for now just because it is more familiar.

In an ideal world, my html **output looks** like this:

```
<p class="tooltip" style="font-size: 73.6207pt;">eyes.
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</p>
<br>
<p class="tooltip" style="font-size: 73.6207pt;">eyes.
  <span class="tooltiptext">filler text</span>
</p>
```

I use a `<br>` because otherwise the text in the `p` tags appears on the same line, but the problem I am having is that the `<br>` is being nested inside of the span tags, so my html output looks like this.

```
<p class="tooltip" style="font-size: 73.6207pt;">eyes.
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text <br></span>
</p>
<p class="tooltip" style="font-size: 73.6207pt;">eyes.
  <span class="tooltiptext">filler text <br></span>
</p>
```

My d3 looks like this:

I've tried moving that `.append("d3")`around, but it either breaks the tooltip, or just messes up the entire visualization.

```
div.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .text(function(d) {
     return d.word;
  })
  .style("font-size", function(d) {
     return scale(parseInt(d.score))  + "pt";
  })
  .append('span')
  .attr("class", "tooltiptext")
  .text("filler text")
  .append("br")
```

Thank you in advance for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3's `.insert()`(present in both [**v3**](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#insert) or [**v4+**](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_insert) selection APIs) only inserts an element once, so it might not to be too useful when you have more than two `<p>` elements. What you can do instead, is to simply iterate through all the `<p>` nodes and use the native JS [`Element.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method to do what you intend to: which is to insert a `<br />` after every `<p>` element.

In this case, we simply do not call `insertBefore()` for the first encountered `<p>` element, and do it subsequently for all the others.

```
var paragraphs = div.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .text(function(d) {
     return d.word;
  })

paragraphs.append('span')
  .attr("class", "tooltiptext")
  .text("filler text");

// Iterate through all inserted paragraphs
paragraphs.each(function(d, i) {

  // Do not insert if first `<p>` is encountered
  if (i === 0)
    return;

  this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), this);
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var div = d3.select('div');
var myData = [{
  word: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
}, {
  word: 'Consectetur adipiscing elit'
}, {
  word: 'Nam id sollicitudin magna'
}, {
  word: 'Pharetra rutrum nisl'
}];

var paragraphs = div.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .text(function(d) {
     return d.word;
  })

paragraphs.append('span')
  .attr("class", "tooltiptext")
  .text("filler text");

// Iterate through all inserted paragraphs
paragraphs.each(function(d, i) {

  // Do not insert if first `<p>` is encountered
  if (i === 0)
    return;
    
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you for teaching me about the insert() method. 
This added the spacing after the <p> tags but strangely enough it only added spacing after the first <p> tag of every 
```<div class="column"">```` in my html? Do you happen to know why that is, I would love to know.

The reason I didn't have spacing after the <p> tags which normally do was because my tooltip was using an inline-block. I commented that out, and everything looks the way I want so I didn't end up using this solution, but thank you :) :)

Comment: @OreArowobusoye `Selection.insert()` only inserts a single element. So, if you need to insert multiple `<br />` elements iteratively, you can iterate through all `<p>` elements and perform a conditional `.insertBefore()`. See my updated answer :)